# Math error switch always ends up zero

Tags: java, math, output

I am writing a small program to find the day of the week using gregorian math.  The following code always outputs a zero into my switch statement resulting in the same output each time.

This is my code:

```
    iSum = (CentCode + iYear + (iYear /4) + MonthCode + iDay);
    iOutput %= iSum;

    switch (iOutput)
    {
        case 0:
            sDay = "sunday";
        break;

        case 1:
            sDay = "monday";
        break;

        case 2: 
            sDay = "tuesday";
        break;

        case 3: 
            sDay = "wednesday";
        break;

        case 4: 
            sDay = "thursday";
        break;

        case 5:
            sDay = "friday";
        break;

        case 6:
            sDay = "saturday";
        break;
}
```

Comment: What are the types of your variables?

Comment: Where are the variables set? What it their value? We can't find your problem without knowing that. Please add it to your post.

Answer (score 3):

```
iOutput %= iSum;
```

is the short form of

```
iOutput = iOutput % iSum;
```

Which is not what you want. I guess you want something like

```
iOutput = iSum % 7;
```

Comment: i need to modulus divide the sum how wouls i do that